# Cannot make chrome extension download a file

Tags: javascript, browser-extension

I have been developing the a chrome extension that works perfectly if I call the methods manually in the console but will only download a blank file or

```js
function extractData() {
    console.log('Extracting data...');
    const elements = document.querySelectorAll('.sf-grid__main-table');
    console.log('Elements:', elements);
    const data = [];
  
    // Add column headings to the first row of the data array
    //data.push({ itemTitle: "itemTitle", sku_number: "SKU", itemPrice: "Price", notes: "Notes" });
    data.push({ itemTitle: "itemTitle", sku_number: "SKU", itemPrice: "Price", notes: "Notes" });
    
    elements.forEach(element => {
      console.log('Processing element:', element);
      const ellipsis = element.querySelector('.ellipsis');
      const itemTitle = ellipsis.querySelector('strong').textContent;
      console.log('itemTitle:', itemTitle);
      const sku_number = ellipsis.textContent.trim().replace(itemTitle, '');
      console.log('sku_number:', sku_number);
      const itemPrice = element.querySelector('.sfl-tooltip-toggle').getAttribute('value');
      console.log('itemPrice:', itemPrice);
  
      // Check if the item price is over 10.00 and the SKU number begins with "AQ," "Y," or "BTLG"
      let notes = "";
      if (parseFloat(itemPrice) > 10.00 && ["AQ", "Y", "BTLG"].includes(sku_number.substring(0, 2))) {
        notes = "potential multibuy";
      }
  
      data.push({ itemTitle, sku_number, itemPrice, notes });
    });
 
  
    // Convert the data array to CSV format
    const csvContent = data.map(row => Object.values(row).join(',')).join('\n');
    console.log('csvContent:', csvContent);
  
    // Create a Blob object from the CSV content
    const blob = new Blob([csvContent], { type: 'text/csv;charset=utf-8' });
  
    // Create an object URL from the Blob object
    const url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
  
    // Use the downloadFile function to download the file
    downloadFile(url, 'data.csv');
  }
  
  function downloadFile(url, fileName) {
    // Create an anchor element
    const anchor = document.createElement('a');
    anchor.style.display = 'none';
    anchor.href = url;
    anchor.download = fileName;
    document.body.appendChild(anchor);
  
    // Click the anchor element
    anchor.click();
  
    // Remove the anchor element
    document.body.removeChild(anchor);
  
    // Revoke the object URL
    URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
  }
  
  // Add a listener for the "click" event of the browser action
  chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(extractData);
```

#manifest.json

```json
{
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "name": "CSV Generator",
    "description": "Extracts data from a table ",
    "version": "1.0",
    "permissions": [
      "activeTab",
      "downloads"
    ],
    "background": {
      "scripts": ["extract-data.js"]
    },
    "browser_action": {
      "default_icon": "icon.png",
      "default_title": "Extract Data"
    }
  }
```

I have tried adding a link to the dom and clicking it also as well as using blobs. Somehow I am losing the data in between the click and the extractData method. Wondering if there is some security issue gotcha I am not aware of?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Background scripts can not parse page data directly. You have to put it on a content script or you can pass the page DOM to the background script [(read more)](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/chrome-extension-message-passing-essentials/).

This is how content script works,

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "name": "CSV Generator",
    "description": "Extracts data from a table ",
    "version": "1.0",
    "permissions": [
      "activeTab",
      "<all_urls>",
      "downloads"
    ],
    "background": {
      "scripts": ["extract-data.js"]
    },
    "content_scripts": [{
      "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
      "js": ["content.js"]
    }],
    "browser_action": {
      "default_icon": "icon.png",
      "default_title": "Extract Data"
    }
  }
```